# Disabling second screen on iPad through 30pin HDMI without disconnecting

Tags: ipad, screen, hdmi

iPad automatically detects when connected to a screen through 30pin HDMI cable and mirrors the content of its screen to the second screen.

Is it possible to disable the second screen from mirroring without disconnecting the cable?
I would like to have a feature which enables and disables the second screen without disconnecting the cable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is to mirror as you note. You can override this by registering to be alerted for screen events. See the docs for [Multiple Display Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html). This will enable you to determine if and what is displayed on the external screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The documentation shows have to produce a second screen which is not a mirror of your first screen. I was unable to enable and disable the mirror second screen without disconnecting it. I would really appreciate it if you could post the code which you think might do this. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Through the UIScreen class you can determine how many screens are available and then handle the second screen, perhaps just showing black. There is some Apple source code here that may help: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ExternalDisplay/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you, this example helped :)